# Multiple Storage

Tags: storage

I want to switch from Windows to Linux soonTM and I wonder how does Linux handle multiple storages.

I have 1 m.2, 1 older sata and a very old HD. Can I simply install Linux on my main m.2 and that's all or do I need to do something else?

Comment: Ubuntu comes available in many ISOs that use different installers. If what you want can't easily be done with one installer; use a different ISO and installer & achieve it using that; as the primary difference between the various Ubuntu products is just what packages are installed by default (*and you can change that post-install anyway*).  You gave no specifics as to what Ubuntu product you're asking about, what release, with more unusual installs achieved by your doing the setup & starting the installer **after** that and using the the "Something else" option & use was pre-setup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install Ubuntu on your M.2 disk.

However, you might also need to set the boot order in BIOS/UEFI, so that the computer boots from this disk by default.